# react state is not updating on onCick function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

i am updating my state on `onClick` Func but its not updating ,

This is my State

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
```

my OnCLick func

```
 const handleBookmarkButtonClick = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    //rest code...including an async func
  };

console.log("loading":loading);
```

the output i got

```
Object {loading: false }
```

my OnCLick func

```
const handleBookmarkButtonClick = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    //rest code...including an async func
};

console.log("loading":loading);
```

i am not getting true ,

Answer (score 0):

Create state like this:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
```

And update state like this:

```
 const handleBookmarkButtonClick = () => { 
  setLoading(true);
 //rest code...including an async func
 };
```

Comment: Check out this example for setting button text from "click me" to "Thanks, been clicked"
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-data-fetching-with-react-hooks-kyjbj4?file=index.js

Comment: But , i have multiple loading state, i thought i should do it with one state , can you explain what is the error

Comment: If it's possible, it becomes difficult to manage. So It's better to use it individually.

Comment: i did but not working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

- The setState is not affected by the async function (try to call the setState separately in the function).
- No other states are not affecting the loading state